# Web Service for SPSiteDataQuery

Tags: web-services, spsitedataquery

Is there a web service(WSDL) to access [spsitedataquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) functions?.

I see web services for sitedata, lists, web and site but there is no spsitedata**query**.
I am interested in getting the list of Lists with ServerTemplate=105.
The other web services, like sitedata,web or lists do not take query filtering parameters when getting the listcollection.

Answer (score 3):

The Lists Web Services is what you're looking for. GetListCollection should do it, and you can filter the results however you'd like. If you want to look across webs, then combine with GetWebCollection from the Webs Web Service.

GetListCollection in the SiteData Web Services looks across all webs in the site, but as you note, no filtering is available.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I am doing right now. Wondering why MSFT did not provision that webservice?

Comment: SharePoint is a very large beastie, and different development teams have worked on the disparate parts, as is very obvious sometimes. The Web Services don't always follow the same logic as the API, though they are usually fairly close.